# Coupon code auto generate not working

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2.4.5

We recently upgraded from 2.4.1 to 2.4.5. After upgrading, the coupon code auto generate function is not working as expected.

When I enter in my information and click "Generate", I get the confirmation message.

[image: Auto generate confirm message]

However, after I search for codes created today, nothing is returned.

[image: No coupon code results]

If I go into my terminal and run this command, they do go and generate.

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor
```

[image: generated codes]

What can I look at to get these codes to generate without having to run that command? Or is that something we need to check if it is running somewhere on our Production site?

Comment: Any luck on fixing this issue?
Seems I have the same problem.

Comment: @LucasVollebergh we did. Looking back in my notes, it appears to have been because of the Magenizr_DeleteOrders module. In app/code/Magenizr/DeleteOrders/Console/Command/DeleteOrdersCommand.php the setAreacode was defined in the “construct” when it should have been in the "execute" command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the cron on your server by running:

```
bin/magento cron:install
```

If after that you need to understand it better you can check the [Configure cron jobs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/configure-cron-jobs.html) documentation.

If you want to go even further and prepare a robust setup for a big store, you can check out the [RabbitMQ setup](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) documentation.